High Memory Usage after migrating from Java 8 to Java 17
Our java Application is deployed in AWS Infra on EC2.
Application running JVM Options - -Xmx51g -Xms24g -Xmn5g. with java 8 during start of the application it was using approx 30g but when migrated to 17 it's starts using complete 51g given as max heap.
GC algo used in java 8 was CMS and with java 17 it's using default G1GC.
can anyone help what could be issue here - is it java 17 with g1gc use this huge memory or it's not freeing up any memory?
As if this is using 51g at the start of application not sure with huge request load what can happen?
I tried with different memory option so one observation when I reduce my XMX values it stays within that limit - it means whatever I am giving as XMX it starts using it.
tried some of the option for G1GC to free up memory like -XX:G1PeriodicGCInterval=* -XX:-G1PeriodicGCInvokesConcurrent but seems it's not helping.

Xmx only defines the heap size. The memory used by the GC itself and other parts of Java is not include din this value. AFIR G1GC requires a bit more memory than the old one of Java 8. G1GC is optimized for multi-core systems, thus make sure it is not running in a single core environment.

Why do you specify -Xmn5g? You surely did not benchmark your application with Java 17/G1GC, to find that this was the best option, when you still have problems with the total heap occupation. Even if this option was useful with your application and Java 8/CMS (which I suspect has never been verified), it doesn’t have to be useful with Java 17/G1GC.

thanks you for the responses. Xmn was given for young gen size along with min and max Heap size. The major challenge in this issue is currently with Java17 If I give XMX as any value it shows memory usage around that only so it's difficult to identify what's it's actual usage? If I give XMX as 40G it stays within that limit and application runs fine. But it doesn't make sense that just because of this issue I give lesser heap memory when I have enough memory available. so just wanted to understand is this genuine case that Java 17/G1GC starts using all the memory given to it as XMX?
